# Can you rely on socket.id as a UID

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Excuse my ignorance, day 2 of node.js/socket.io

I'm looking for a way to uniquely identify users for use in a database queuing system. I read a lot about using Express's session cookie, however I've noticed socket.id seems to be an UID that socket.io is already using.

Therefore I have been using socket.id to identify my users both in the database, and in creating private "rooms" to communicate with just them.

Is this a terrible idea?

Comment: The big question for me is, will this be unique among multiple instances running at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A socket ID is just that - it uniquely identifies a socket. It doesn't uniquely identify a user, and it's definitely not intended to be used for that purpose. A single user (in many applications) might have multiple connections (and therefore multiple sockets with different ID's). Also, every time they connect they will be assigned a new ID.

So you obviously shouldn't use a `socket.id` as a user ID. Mustafa points out that you could reassign `socket.id` to a user ID, but I tend to think that's a very bad idea for two reasons:

1. `socket.id` is supposed to uniquely identify a socket, so you would run into problems when a single user has multiple sockets open.
2. Socket.IO, uses that ID internally a lot for storing things in hashtables, and if you change the ID, you might get unexpected results and hard to track down bugs. I haven't tested it, but looking at the Socket.IO source, that's what I would expect.

Better to generate ID's using another method then associate a user with a socket (for example, during the handshake using data from the cookie).

`socket.set(key, value, callback)` is the method explicitly intended to be used for associating your own data (like a user ID) with a socket connection, and is the only one guaranteed to be safe.

Comment: Thank you for this information! The multiple tab/session isn't an issue for the problem I am solving, so it's good to hear I can use this for that purpose. However I will look to use cookies if such a need to identify/persist multiple sessions presents itself.

Answer (score 1):

When the socket.io sockets are created, you can add variables as you wish to socket object. `socket.userid = getUserID()` will work fine. It is better to make assinging UIDs in database, and add them to socket objects when their authentication is succesful.